# how to set the value of matrix in parallel with mex and openmp?

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, openmp, mex

I have a problem while handling a huge matrix in mex. This is my code. I want to sum the value when the index is the same.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
      for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
          C[(mwSize)*Ar++ - 1] += *Av++;
      }
```

It got segmentation fault. I think it's because we update the matrix in parallel.  But I am not sure how to handle it because the size is too big (800000x1). Please help me, thank you.

EDITED. Here is the full code.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSize i, n, m ;
    double *Ar, *Av, *C ;

      n = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
      m = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[2]);

      Ar = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      Av = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
      plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,1,mxREAL);
      C = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
      for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
          C[(mwSize)Ar[i] - 1] += Av[i];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Aren't you getting race condition doing these Ar++ and Av++ in parallel?

Comment: When you split the work on an array by `omp parallel for`, you should then use the index `i` when accessing the elements. Also, please, show us what is `Ar`, `Av`, `C`, `n`, and `mwSize`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I have changed the code, is it still in the race condition?

Comment: @DanielLangr Please check the edited version. I have provided the full code. Ar is array of index while Av is the array of value. I want to sum all of the value in the same index and save it in C.

Comment: The problem is (at least; we don't see the data) that you need to synchronize writes to `C`. In OpenMP, you can use `#pragma omp atomic update` for `+=` operation. However, note that most hardware does not support floating-point atomics and a compiler needs to translate them into atomic compare-exchange instructions, which may be quite inefficient. Generally, a better approach would be to partition the whole task such that each thread writes to its exclusive part of elements of `C`. Then, you wouldn't need any synchronization.

Comment: Also note that in the original version, this `*Ar++` was very wrong. First, such a _fetch-add_ operation would need to be atomic (`#pragma omp atomic capture`), and second, even then it would be terribly inefficient since every iteration would need to be synchronized within memory subsystem. `Ar[i]` is much better solution.

Comment: What is the size of `C`? Are all values of `Ar` strictly positives? @DanielLangr I think an array reduction would be better than atomic operations if `C` is small and `n` big.

Comment: Do you know if any of the Ar values are duplicates?  I.e., is there a possibility of a clash for the updating?  Can you sort the Ar values first?